# How do I catch "returns" from popups from a different file than my "main"?

Tags: python, import, popup, pyqt, return

I have a Mainwindow and from there I'm calling a popup. The popup has to options to click. Now, how can I "return" the clicked option to my mainwindow?

I'm importing the file where the popup is to my main:

```
import pbarpre
[...]
def callpopup(self):
   pbarpre.Popupedit()
[...]
```

pbarpre.py:

```
class Popupedit(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.ja = QtGui.QPushButton(u"Y")
    self.ja.setFixedSize(90,25)
    self.nein = QtGui.QPushButton(u"N")
    self.nein.setFixedSize(90,25)
    self.nein.clicked.connect(self.exit)
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(u"blablabla")
    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(self.ja)
    hbox.addWidget(self.nein)
    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(self.label)
    vbox.setAlignment(self.label, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    vbox.addLayout(hbox)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
    self.setWindowTitle(u'?')
    self.setFixedSize(300,100)
    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Popup)
    self.exec_()

  def exit(self):
    self.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add method to return some values

```
def getValues(self):
    return value


popup = pbarpre.Popupedit()
if popup.exec_():
    value = popup.getValues()
```

Comment: it worked, but with `if popup.exec_:`. You have to remove the "()". Thanks!

Comment: @Hubschr that can't be because you need to enter the event loop of the dialog window so you have to call the `exec_` function. If you remove the `()` you aren't actually getting user input into the dialog, you're just testing if there is an `exec_` method on your popup and since this is the case, immediately get the default value. What makes you think you have to use `if popup.exec_:`?

Comment: If I use `if popup.exec_()` my popup is called two times.First time because of `popup = pbarpre.Popupedit()` and second time because of `if popup.exec_():` (I think...? ) But thanks to your comment, I noticed that I dont need to use `if popup.exec_:`. I just call my popup, where there are only 2 options to click and then I call the `getvalue()` function